# javascript onkeypressed not giving current text box content

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I have an html form like this:

```
<form id="boxy" action="layout.html" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" id="a" onkeypress="Boxy.Check(this);">
</form>
```

Invoking javascript like this:

```
Boxy.Check = function() {
    input = document.getElementById(this.currentSelector.id).value;
    console.log("\"" + input + "\"");
};
```

However, `this.value` is the previous value before `onkeypress`.

For example, if I just type "A" into the form, `console.log()` prints "". And if I type "AA", `console.log` prints "A".

Is there a way to get the current content of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use onkeyup.

var KeyID = (window.event) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;

values for KeyID are:

```
> 16 (Shift)
> 17 (Ctrl)
> 18 (Alt)
> 19 (Pause)
> 37 (Left)
> 38 (Up)
> 39 (Right)
> 40 (Down)
```

This way you can check whether such a key is pressed.

Untested but this should work. Please let me know if something doesn't work as it should.

EDIT: Added cross-browser support

Comment: This works, but occurs when any key is pressed not just when characters are input.

Comment: I think you might have to check which key was pressed to prevent this. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using getElementById

```
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="Boxy.Check();">

Boxy.Check = function() {
    input = document.getElementById(
        document.getElementById('a').currentSelector.id
    ).value;
    console.log("\"" + input + "\"");
};
```

using PeeHaa's advice with unkeyup

Comment: this doesn't change the behavior. I need to use `this.currentSelector.id` because this code is being used for multiple forms.